# how to show *.mpp files in my iphone application?

Tags: iphone, image, file

I have a problem in showing *.mpp (microsoft project files) in my app. I thought of showing in image format but i dont know how to convert it into image format. or is there any other way to view mpp files.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I have doubts you can with the standard SDK.

You should first convert your .mpp file to a more convenient format, such as pdf or an image format, like png, using a tool like [Zamzar](http://www.zamzar.com/) or something similar. Then, depending on your output, on the iPhone you would use a UIWebView to display a PDF or an UIImageView to view an image.

Comment: thank you luvieere,
if you have any idea in detail regarding this (not only mpp files) converting to an image please share it.
thank u in advance